# Running a function inside a function

Tags: python, tkinter, reportlab

A help here please, Everytime I click the button at a different time, the new generated pdf file keeps replacing the existing pdf file. Please, how to I save the same file name in the same directory but with different times and date dates?

```
from tkinter import *
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from T_invoice import my_templet  
import sqlite3
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk


my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry(”900x650”)
my_w.title(”christ”)

def PDFPrint():
    my_path = (”E:\my_pdf.pdf”)
    c = canvas.Canvas(my_path, pagesize=letter)
    c = my_temp(c) 
    c.setFillColorRGB(0, 0, 1)
    c.setFont(”Helvetica”, 14)
    row_gap = 0.3 
    line_y = 7.9 
    total = 0

    conn = sqlite3.connect(”E:\login.db”)
    con = conn.cursor()
    query = (”select * from sales ”)
    con.execute(query)
    saleslist = con.fetchall()

    for i in range(0, len(saleslist)):
        saleslist[i] = list(saleslist[i])
        con.execute(”select product_d,product_p from products where product_id=?” (int(saleslist[i][2]),))
        l = con.fetchall()
        s = (str(saleslist[i[4])).split('-')
        saleslist[i][4] = s[2] + ” - ” + s[1] + ” - ” + s[0]
        saleslist[i]=[saleslist[i][0], saleslist[i][1], saleslist[i][2], l[0][0], saleslist[i][3],l[0][1] * 1, saleslist[i][4], saleslist[i][5]]
        saleslist[i] = tuple(saleslist[i])
    for dt in saleslist:
        c.drawString(0.1 * inch, line_y * inch, str(dt[3]))
        c.drawRightString(4.5 * inch, line_y * inch, str(dt[5]))
        c.drawRightString(5.5 * inch, line_y * inch, str(dt[4]))
        sub_total = round( (dt[5] * dt[4]), 1)
        c.drawRightString(7 * inch, line_y * inch, str(sub_total))
        total = round(total + sub_total, 2)
        line_y = line_y - row_gap

    total_final = total
    c.setFont("Times-Bold", 22)
    c.setFillColorRGB(1, 0, 0)
    c.drawRightString(7 * inch, -0.3 * inch, str(total_final))
    c.showPage()
    c.save() subprocess.Popen([”E\pdf\my_pdf.pdf”], shell=True)

reportbut = Button(my_w, text=”report”, font=”roboto 14”, bd=5, width=8, bg=”yellow”,command=PDFPrint)
reportbut.place(x=510, y=18, height=40)

my_w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what exactly you're getting from your code.  What errors are you getting(if any)?  What did you want to happen with ```subprocess.Popen(["E\pdf\my_pdf.pdf"], shell=True)```?     This line looks strange.

Comment: One other thing.  Your paths need to either be using rawstring or escaped.  i.e. ```"E:\\pdf\\my_pdf.pdf"```  or ```r'E:\pdf\my_pdf.pdf'```.

Comment: Also, why are you tagging javascript, php, html and css?  And to answer your question, you're not changing the file names, and thusly, the files are replaced.

Comment: I don't know of a file system which will store multiple versions with the same filename in the way you imply. I think you'll have to add the time and date to the filename.

Comment: My code does not return any error. It works perfectly but I wanted to save the same file name with the current date and time when I click the button. When I run my code, the previous saved file is replaced by the current file. In simple terms, I want to duplicate the file name as many times as I keep running the code through the button click.

Comment: @Maliamungu it is not possible what you want to achieve. `Please, how to I save the same file name in the same directory but with different times and date dates` would mean you would have two files with the same name in the same directory. That's neither in Mac OS. Windows or Linux is possible as far as I know. It would be a unique OS / Filesystem feature.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, it seems not possible to have more than `my_pdf.pdf` in one directory at a time

What you could do is rename the existing file before you save the current file.

```py
import os
import time

pdf_name = r"E\pdf\my_pdf.pdf";
archive_name =  r"E\pdf\" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "_my_pdf.pdf" ;

os.rename(pdf_name, archive_name);
```